# Any way to make bounties 'double or nothing'

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I can't think of a way to do this, but say you offer a bounty, there should be a way to get your original bounty back plus the same amount again (e.g. you offer +100, you get back +200).

This could be for several reasons - no satisfactory answer, etc...

It would make bounties more interesting.

Failing that, a simple **Bounty Slot Machine** would work just as well.

Comment: Bounties are **advertising**, not a gambling device. You don't get your bounty back now, why would getting **double** back help anyone but people trying to gain reputation for all the wrong reasons?

Comment: Bounty: 500  Q: *How long is a piece of string?*

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure that's not how bounties work. You may be confusing a "bounty" for a "bet" or a "wager".

Comment: I wouldn't see a problem with this if you left out the part about getting your original bounty back. Instead of awarding the bounty at the end of the week, if you don't have a satisfactory answer, double the amount and keep the bounty open for an additional week.

Comment: @Plutonix - strings aren't integers

Comment: @Plutonix & @JonMarkPerry: `Dim answer As Integer = New String("How long is a piece of string?").Length`

Comment: Its a set of 3 reels that spin and stop randomly. When the reels stop, if the win line (the center line across the vertical reels) consists of 3 the same, you win. They are usually played for money, but i thought we could play with our rep. Amazing idea I know. Why? Because SO and SE in general needs (a small) makeover.

Comment: @Brandon B - really, that's not very clever...

Comment: okay, perhaps not random gambling, but 50 reps if you can name a capital city with a double letter in 10secs (i wont honor it BTW)

Comment: just coz you lost...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals_in_alphabetical_order gives: accra, addis ababa, amman, for starters. i came up with canberra (capital of australia)

Answer (score 3):

This would definitely increase the number of bounties that were offered, but the rep inflation from its abuse would destroy the rep economy.

Comment: my Q comes from my Q @ http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6042/packing-a-6-by-12-lego-tile, I was going to offer a smallish bounty, but I can't afford it, and the incentive for me to do so is practically non-existent.

Comment: but i guess you cant do bounties on beta's anyway

Comment: I've used bounties many times, either because I want the answer badly, or to reward a good answer, or on MSE to bring attention to a question.  You would probably do better at LEGOS SE if you would edit your clarifying comment into the question and made it better.  You could also put a graphic in, and that would draw in more answers.  You need to work as hard on your question as you expect the answerers to work.

Comment: @Lance is for the tip, added an edit, not sure about image - will look in

Comment: added an image aswell.